# Android Apps crashes on phone

Tags: android

I have just started on developing android apps and my first application crashes on my phone.
I am using eclipse as SDK and my phone has andoid ver 2.3.6
Here are the details

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="calc_fare"
        android:text="@string/calc_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/result_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Taxi Fare Calculator</string>
    <string name="edit_text">Enter Meter Reading</string><string name="calc_button">Calculate</string><string name="result_text" >Actual Fare</string><string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

mainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.taxifarecalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    public void calc_fare() {
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        EditText resultText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
        Double mtr = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
        Double fare=mtr*103;
        resultText.setText(fare.toString());


    }

}
```

The app hangs and crashes when I press the calc button which ideally should call the calc_fare method which, in turn, should populate the text view

Regards
Parikshit

Comment: Change method declaration for Button onClick  `public void calc_fare()` to  `public void calc_fare(View v)` and post log also with question when your app is crashing

Comment: on researching log cat I found this: 01-07 12:11:39.148: E/AndroidRuntime(10313): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calc_fare(View) in the activity class com.example.taxifarecalculator.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'

can anybody point out where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

change this method arguments from

```
public void calc_fare() {

    }
```

to be like the following:

```
public void calc_fare(View v) {

    }
```

Comment: add those two declaration in the onCreate() method                 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
EditText resultText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result_text);

Comment: Hello Husam,
I added  and now the app is crashing at startup.

Answer (score 0):

You are Creating the Listener of calc_fare in your layout but your not making it to listen when you click on it 
and you must be caused app crashed 
your button is a view and your not passing view when you are handling the listener of your view 
Just Simpliy add View in your Method

```
public void Calc_fare(){

//add your code here  

}
```

like this

```
    public void Calc_fare(View view){
//add your code here 
}
```

now it will pick the listener and will perform the desired functionality

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have check out code and done some relevant changes. The method which you have defined in the xml file for the Button is not getting accessible ,so i have implemented the onClick of the Button explicitly and its working fine.

Check out this way:

> ```
>  public class MainActivity extends Activity{
>         EditText editText;
>        TextView resultText;
>        Button m_btn;
>       View m_view;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>     editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
>  resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text);
>     m_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
>     m_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
>     {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View p_v) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>             calc_fare();
>         }
>     });
> }
> public void calc_fare() {       
>     Double mtr = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
>     Double fare=mtr*103;
>     resultText.setText(fare.toString());
> }
> ```
>
> }

Remove your `onClick` event from the xml file of your layout and try out this way. Its working fine absolutely.

Comment: Hello Grishu, I tried to implement your code but it fails with follwoing exception: 
01-07 14:25:58.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 14:25:58.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12925): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
01-07 14:25:58.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):  at com.example.taxifarecalculator.MainActivity.calc_fare(MainActivity.java:47)
01-07 14:25:58.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12925):  at com.example.taxifarecalculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31

Comment: Just try to clean your application and build again and then run. It will work then.

Comment: Have you removed the `onClick` event from your layout file `Button` view? If not then please remove it first.